# Kotlin change property value

Tags: android, kotlin

I have generic function, which should bind universal object to views. I already handle getting data from objects and get fields name from view. But now I have a problem with assign this data.

This function iterate for every element in layout and get id, then call get on object function (the name of layout element have this same names as in object). In IF statement I want to assign the `objectValue` (String) to the TextView

```
class UniversalViewHolder<T : Any>(val bindingAny: ViewDataBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(bindingAny.root){
    fun bind(elemAny: Any){
        var binding = bindingAny.javaClass
        binding.fields.forEach {
            try {
                val objectValue = readInstanceProperty<String>(elemAny,it.name)
                Log.d(TAG,it.name+" "+objectValue)
                if (it.type == TextView::class.java){
                    //here bind
                }
            }catch (ex: NoSuchElementException){
                Log.e(TAG, "NO ELEMENT AT THIS FIELD "+ it.name)
            }catch (ex:Exception){
                Log.e(TAG,"CRASH AT THIS ELEM: " + it.name+"\n"+ex.stackTraceToString())
            }
        }
    }
```

I have property mText in bindingAny and then in date but how I can access the mText property in this?
[image]

Next I try to change this data by `binding.fields` I can recive Field object which contains type but I dont find any opportunity to change text
[image]

Also I try to access to method function setText(charSequence) but I get a cast problem

#EDIT
My solution

```
    fun bind(elemAny: Any,context: Context){
        val binding = bindingAny.javaClass

        binding.fields.forEach { field ->
            try {
                val objectValue = readInstanceProperty<String>(elemAny,field.name)
                Log.d(TAG,field.name+" "+objectValue)
                if (field.type == TextView::class.java){

                    arrayTextView.forEach {
                        if(context.resources.getResourceName(it.id).contains(field.name)){
                            it.text = objectValue
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch (ex: NoSuchElementException){
                Log.e(TAG, "NO ELEMENT AT THIS FIELD "+ field.name)
            }catch (ex:Exception){
                Log.e(TAG,"CRASH AT THIS ELEM: " + field.name+"\n"+ex.stackTraceToString())
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    private var arrayTextView : ArrayList<TextView> = ArrayList()
    private fun searchLeaf(root: ViewGroup,context: Context){
        while(true){
            root.forEach {
                if(it::class == MaterialTextView::class || it::class == TextView::class){
                    Log.d(TAG,context.resources.getResourceName(it.id))
                    arrayTextView.add(it as TextView)
//                }else if ((it as ViewGroup).size == 0) {
                }
                else if((it as ViewGroup).size != 0){
                    try{
                        searchLeaf(it as ViewGroup,context)
                    }catch (ex:Exception){ }
                }
            }
        break
        }
    }
```

Comment: What error message exactly you are getting?

Comment: When I try to access method function?

Comment: You said you are having cast problem. I am asking that

Comment: Now i do it different way  `it.type.methods.filter { it.name == "setText" }[1].invoke((bindingAny as CardMessageBinding).message,"test")`
this is in if statement but how I can do this `bindingAny as CardMessageBinding)` more universal? or if you look at photo number 1, how I can access this date object?

Comment: This above works but invoke needs 2 parametrs object(TextView) and String, now I have to find way to get this date as TextView

Comment: When I try to put in invoke ```(bindingAny as T).javaClass.fields[1].type```, I got this error `Expected receiver of type android.widget.TextView, but got java.lang.Class<android.widget.TextView>`

Answer (score 0):

if someone looking for answer. I found the way how it's possible to handle this problem. I just take binding.root and cast it to ViewGroup,

`val x = (bindingAny.root as ViewGroup).children.first() as ViewGroup)`

and this way I have access to views, now I have search all TextViews like in binary tree but with n leaf